# is a real world education grammatically correct？

Tags: grammaticality

Part-time work should be regarded as a real world education
can I use “a” in front of education？
Is the phrase “ a real-world education ”correct？

Comment: Hi again - this is also not a question about learning English. It sounds like what you need is a grammar-checker. Have you tried 'Grammarly'? If you have a specific question about a point of language then those are welcome.

Comment: Do the phrase really exits then？

Answer (score 1):

You can, because "education" can be both countable and non-countable.  But non count (with no a) is probably better. Non-count is more common and it matches the non-count word "work". So unless specifically need to use the countable word (for reasons you haven't given here) don't use "a".

Comment: I think the countable version sounds a bit old-fashioned and is generally used in set phrases ("a sentimental education", "That was quite an education", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

"Part-time work is **a** real-world education" is grammatical but would be idiomatic only in a conversation about the various kinds of real world education, or what constitutes a real world education, or when differentiating between real-world education and something that is not considered  (by someone) to be such. For example:

> Some people would not consider being a "roadie" a real-world education, since it is often accompanied by a lifestyle of heavy partying.
>
> I enjoyed taking courses on fantasy film-making but my father insisted that I find a part-time job, to get a real-world education.